# Single word/phrase for "unindent and unalign"?

Tags: typography, alignment, terminology, spacing

[image: Indentation and Alignment]

In the image, "dolor sit" line is "indented" and "aligned". If you pull that line all the way to the first column, it would be "unindented and unaligned". What would be a single word/phase for the action of "unindenting and unaligning" something?

That is, I'm looking for a word/phrase that means "the action of *undoing* indentation and alignment". I feel like just "unindent" or "dedent" doesn't cut it, because it is also aligned, not just indented.

Comment: Would unpositioned work for you? I can't work out if that covers the definitions of both words.

Comment: Possibly. I would like it more if it sounds more "technical" though 

Comment: Hmm, I understand, I'll scratch my head a bit more and see what I can find

Answer (score 2):

## [Flush left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_alignment#:%7E:text=for%20that%20script.-,Flush%20left,left%2Dto%2Dright%20text.)

Flush left, for most English language typesetting, means to align text on the left side without indents or any odd alignment. Indents, or specific variations beyond the flush left, would be specified in addition to specifying the flush left.

In typesetting and editing, flush left is indicated by an open left bracket ... `[` See image below.

[image]

<sub>[ image source: http://thinkingwithtype.com/extras/ ]</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the verb ***to justify*** or its participle ***justified***. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/justify) defines "justify as:

> to space (lines of text) so that the lines come out even at the margin; to make even by spacing lines of text
>
> - e.g. justified margins